# Batch file complicated if sequence returns errors.

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to have users login and when they do it sets their power or rank. The ranks are Admin User and Guest. I need to do the code below for every command in the program. It returns ) was not expected at this time. Any idea why? For this command all the users should be able to access it but later I will need to set certain things for each group.

```
if %inputCommand%==/help (
  if %power%==Admin (
goto helpInfo
  ) else (
    if %power%==User (
  goto helpInfo
) else (
  if %power%==Guest (

      ) else (
        goto powerReadFailed
      )
    )
  )
) else (
goto readInputCommandTwo
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if "%inputCommand%"=="/help" (
  if "%power%"=="Admin" (
goto helpInfo
  ) else (
    if "%power%"=="User" (
  goto helpInfo
) else (
  if "%power%"=="Guest" (
        rem
      ) else (
        goto powerReadFailed
      )
    )
  )
) else (
goto readInputCommandTwo
    )
```

Comment: Other "empty" commands (e.g. `type nul`) would work, too. Removing the need for an empty branch by inverting the condition (`if not "%power%"=="Guest"`) would be a better approach, though.

Comment: Yes, I know :-) , but I don't know, what the OP wants to do with his `else` code. So I only made it running.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated?

how about

```
for %%a in (admin user guest) do if /i "%power"=="%%a" (
 for %%b in (help somethingelse whatever) do if /i "%inputcommand"=="%%b" (
 goto %%a%%b
 )
 goto %%ainvalidcommand
)
:powerreadfailed
```

you can then set up labels

```
adminhelp userhelp guesthelp
adminsomethingelse usersomethingelse guetsomethingelse
...
```

It's perfectly legitimate to write

```
:adminhelp
:userhelp
echo admin and user get the same help
```

and adding a new user-class or command isn't hard...

( IF `/i` means make a case-insensitive comparison)